# Sql Server Pivot with multiple columns from a record

Tags: sql-server

I am using Sql Server 2014.  I currently have a table which looks something like this:

```
labNumber   parameter   result  date
18897       Nitrate     <0      1/20/2007
18897       Coliform    NEG     1/21/2007
18897       Arsenic     1       1/22/2007
```

I need to create a view where there is only one record which would look like this:

```
labNumber   nitate  nitrateDate  coliform   coliformDate    arsenic   arsenicDate
18897       <0      1/20/2007    NEG        1/21/2007       1         1/22/2007
```

Before I realized that each records with the same lab number had a different date I hada view using PIVOT which looked like this:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM  (SELECT  labNumber, result, parameter 
         FROM ResultsTable) src 
         PIVOT (MAX(result) 
         FOR parameter IN ([Nitrate], [Coliform], [Arsenic])) p
```

I am completely stumped how to accomplish the results I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have just record per `parameter`, Here is one way using `conditional aggregate`

```
SELECT labNumber,
       Max(CASE WHEN parameter = 'Nitrate' THEN result END) AS nitate,
       Max(CASE WHEN parameter = 'Nitrate' THEN date END) nitateDate,
       Max(CASE WHEN parameter = 'Coliform' THEN result END) Coliform,
       Max(CASE WHEN parameter = 'Coliform' THEN date END) ColiformDate,
       Max(CASE WHEN parameter = 'Arsenic' THEN result END) Arsenic,
       Max(CASE WHEN parameter = 'Arsenic' THEN date END) ArsenicDate
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY labNumber
```

Another approach by `unpivoting` and `pivoting` the data

```
SELECT labNumber,
       Nitrate,
       NitrateDate,
       Coliform,
       ColiformDate,
       Arsenic,
       ArsenicDate
FROM  (SELECT labNumber,
              intr,
              col
       FROM   Yourtable
              CROSS apply (VALUES (result,parameter),
                                  (convert(varchar(20),[date],120),parameter + 'Date')) cs(intr, col))a
      PIVOT (Max(intr)
            FOR col IN (Nitrate,
                        NitrateDate,
                        Coliform,
                        ColiformDate,
                        Arsenic,
                        ArsenicDate))pv
```